# How to calculate speed from time and distance...

Tags: unit-of-measure

I understand the formula for calculating speed.  However, I'm not very good at the conversions.  I'm trying to figure out the speed of a baseball pitch, based on the distance and time.

A ball pitched at a major league distance of 60 feet 6 inches takes 0.4342105s how fast is the pitch?  The answer should be around 95mph (https://www.omnicalculator.com/other/speed)

How do I calculate mph from feet and milliseconds? Showing conversions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The ball is going 60 feet 6 inches per 0.4342105s

Comment: Do it step by step. The ball travels 60 feet 6 in 0.4342105s. First possible step: the ball travels $\frac{60 \ feet \ 6}{  0.4342105}$  in 1 second